# Encontrar onde consulta pesada é gerada

Tags: php, cakephp-2

Bom dia 
Preciso encontrar onde no CakePHP 2.5.2 esta consulta é realizada:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM umatabela WHERE status = 1`

Tem uma model onde esta tabela é referenciada, e pode ser que seja referenciada em outros locais.

Pelo Debugkit estou rodando todos os possiveis locais e nao encontro.

Haveria um meio melhor, de rastrear, do que procurar pelas models ou rodar cada script e olhar no debugkit?

Comment: Voce esta fazendo uma paginação? Componentes de paginação realizam o select com o COUNT para pegar a quantidade total.

Comment: Imagino nao ter opçao o pior que fica em cima de uma view dai fica mais lento . Imagino apenas forçar mais criterios de pesquisa . Apenas nao encontro no debugkit talves por ser uma consulta interna que o cake faz nao apareça no debugkit então

Comment: Parceiro... vc tem certeza que a query é exatamente assim??? se tiver, você pode usar a própria busca da sua IDE (se vc usa uma)... basta dar um Ctrl + H digitar essa query no campo e pedir para buscar em todo o seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Pode estar em diversos lugares mas, por padrão, ficariam no model com nome similar a tabela, geralmente no singular.

Uma chamada comum que poderia gerar este sql seria:

`$this->find("count")`.

Ou

`$UmaTabela->find('count')`.

O ORM do cake converte métodos `find()` em query's.

Se buscar no projeto `find('count')` ou `find("count")` irá acabar achando.

Caso você tenha debugger, basta rastrear o stack trace e ver os métodos que foram chamados.

O where 1=1 é adicionado por segurança quando não há condições de busca, prevenção de sql injection.